# Asymptotics of coefficients in the expansion of $\log\cos x$

Tags: real-analysis, combinatorics, asymptotics

Let $c_n$ be the coefficient of $x^{2n}$ in the Maclauren expansion of $\log\cos x$. What can be said about the asymptotics of $c_n$ as $n\to\infty$?

I expect that this question is routine, but I have not studied combinatorics and don't even know where to get started. This is just one small piece of a larger question but I think I can handle the other aspects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We'll write $[x^n] f(x)$ to mean the coefficient of $x^n$ in the Maclaurin expansion of $f(x)$.

Since

$$
\frac{d}{dx} \log \cos x = - \tan x
$$

we have

$$
[x^n] \log \cos x = -\frac{1}{n} [x^{n-1}] \tan x.
$$

In particular,

$$
[x^{2n}] \log \cos x = -\frac{1}{2n} [x^{2n-1}] \tan x = - \frac{T_n}{(2n)!},
$$

where $T_n$ is the $n^\text{th}$ [tangent number](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TangentNumber.html).  The asymptotics can then be found by applying the [asymptotic formula for the Bernoulli numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number#Asymptotic_approximation).  The resulting asymptotic series is

$$
[x^{2n}] \log \cos x \approx - \frac{2^{2n}-1}{n\pi^{2n}} \left(1+\frac{1}{2^{2n}} + \frac{1}{3^{2n}} + \frac{1}{4^{2n}} + \cdots \right).
$$

Comment: You're welcome.  It's also interesting that the leading order asymptotics can be got by noticing that $$\log \cos x \sim \log(\pi/2+x) \quad \text{as } x \to -\pi/2^+$$ and $$\log\cos x \sim \log(\pi/2-x) \quad \text{as } x \to \pi/2^-$$ then calculating $$[x^{2n}]\log\cos x \sim [x^{2n}] \Bigl(\log(\pi/2+x) + \log(\pi/2-x)\Bigr) = \frac{1}{n} \left(\frac{2}{\pi}\right)^{2n},$$ though I don't know how to justify the $\sim$ yet.

Comment: ...I'll admit, I only used the leading term anyway.